# Equivalent forms of Fourier restriction conjecture

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, interpolation

this question is posted in [mathstackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4481420/a-question-for-the-equivalent-form-of-restriction-conjecture), but it seems that no one answers it. Sorry to the administrator if this question is not appropriate on Mathoverflow.

I'm reading Pertti Maattila's book **Fourier analysis and Hausdorff dimension**, and I have a question on the equivalent form of the restriction conjecture in Chapter 19. The book says that the following conjectures are **equivalent**:

- Conjecture 19.5 $\|\hat{f}\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n\ )}\leq C(n,q)\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\,)}$, for $q>\frac{2n}{n-1}$ and $q=\frac{n+1}{n-1}p^\prime$.
- Conjecture 19.6 $\|\hat{f}\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n\ )}\leq C(n,q)\|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})}$, for $q>\frac{2n}{n-1}$.
- Conjecture 19.7 $\|\hat{f}\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n\ )}\leq C(n,q)\|f\|_{L^q(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\,)}$, for $q>\frac{2n}{n-1}$.

I can understand how Conjecture 19.5 implies 19.6 and Conjecture 19.7 implies 19.6. While Conjecture 19.6 implies 19.7 is a theorem due to Bourgain. After proving the equivalence of 19.6 and 19.7, the book says that 19.6 implies 19.5 can be done by interpolation. I can not understand why one can do this by interpolation. Due to my knowledge, we have

- $\|\hat{f}\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n\ )}\leq C(n,q)\|f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\, )}$, for $q>\frac{2n}{n-1}$.
- $\|\hat{f}\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n\ )}\leq C(n,q)\|f\|_{L^q(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\,)}$, for $q>\frac{2n}{n-1}$.

Then for any $\theta\in[0,1]$, let $\frac{1}{q_0}=\frac{1-\theta}{q}+\frac{\theta}{q}$ ($q_0$ is just $q$ itself here), and $\frac{1}{p_0}=\frac{1-\theta}{\infty}+\frac{\theta}{q}=\frac{\theta}{q}$, we have

- $\|\hat{f}\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n\ )}\lesssim \|f\|_{L^{p_0}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\,)}$, for $q>\frac{2n}{n-1}$.

In order to get Conjecture 19.5, we only need to find a $\theta\in[0,1]$ so that $q=\frac{n+1}{n-1}p_0^\prime$, this is equivalent to $q=\theta+\frac{n+1}{n-1}$. But this contradicts to the condition $q>\frac{2n}{n+1}$, since $q=\theta+\frac{n+1}{n-1}\leq1+\frac{n+1}{n-1}=\frac{2n}{n-1}$. So there isn't such $\theta$.

I can not understand why Conjecture 19.6 implies 19.5 by interpolation. Do I misunderstand something?
[Here is a screeshot of Mattila's book in Chapter 19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbXNV.png)